# azure AD connect certicate

Tags: active-directory, azure, connect

I am configuring SSO through Azure AD Connect and an Oracle app, I could not find the appropriate certificate to include it in the wallet.

Can someone help me with a download link please.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What product are you using and what is meant by "wallet"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using SAML then the SAML cert is available on the single sign on page of the enterprise app panel in AAD.